# Grails g:select list with "Yes" value

Tags: list, grails, select

I have something like this is my view:

```
<g:select name="book" from="${['Yes', 'No']}"/>
```

How can I do this in the controller:

```
if(params.book== "Yes"){
            doSomething()
        }
```

Because that if is always false, and I'm sure its because `params.book== "Yes"` is a wrong way to do it, thats why it always tells me it's false.

Comment: first of all you can control you incoming params by print them out -> print params. in my opinion your exmpale looks good. depending on your selection you should receive Yes or No.

Comment: Could you provide how you are submitting this value to the controller?

Comment: i found out the error. The stated code is right. I wasn't able to save an object inside the "if" statment because i was using wrong syntx. Was using 'object.prop == something' instead of 'object.prop = something'. Sometimes when you are coding for so long you can block yourself in an easy and stupied thing like this. Thanks for the time spent guy, i @solved the problem.